# Access a method's variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, methods, comparison, access-modifiers

I am new to Java so I need help.

How can I access the variables of the method `method1` and compare them with the variable `int c`? What should I return?

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    int c = 30;

 // I want to compare c with a, for example:

    if (c > a)
    {
         System.out.println(c + " is greater than " + a);
    }

}
```

I want to do the above comparison without touching `method1()`

```
public double method1(){

    int a = 10; int b = 20;

    if (a > b)
    { 
        System.out.println(a + " is greater than " + b); 
    } 
    else if (a < b)
    { 
        System.out.println(b + " is greater than " + a); 
    }

   //What should I return?

    return ????; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access the variables of the method "method1" [...] without touching the method1()?

You can't.

Local variables in a method are only accessible inside that method. And if that method doesn't give you a way to see them, then without modifying the method, you can't see them.

Since `a` is always 10, you could do `if (c > 10)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you are writing  "int c = 30;" directly below main then it becomes global variable.

Global Variable means: "c" can be accessed inside methods(anywhere in same class).

if you are writing "int c = 30;" inside particular method than you cannot access outside that particular method.

Following is example of global variable.

public static void main (String [] args){

```
int c = 30;
```

public double method1(){

```
int a = 10; 

if (a > c)
{ 
    System.out.println(a + " is greater than " + c); 
    return a;
} 
else if (a < c)
{ 
    System.out.println(c + " is greater than " + a);
    return b; 
}
```

}

I hope it works for you.